# Are there any known issues with Daemon Tools Lite and Windows 7 32-bit RTM?

Tags: windows-7, compatibility

The download page for [Daemon Tools Lite Commercial](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtLite) (the free one) version 4.30.4 says that Windows 7 Beta is supported (SPTD 1.58). However the Pro [Standard](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtproStd) and [Advanced](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtproAdv) versions say Windows 7 is "*fully*" supported and uses SPTD 1.60.

So, should I ignore the warning from the Windows 7 "Program Compatibility Assistant" and just go ahead and install the Lite version? Or should I wait until this is fixed (or buy the Pro version)?

Has anyone encountered any issues with the Lite version running on Windows 7 32-bit RTM?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend just scrapping Daemon Tools and going with [Virtual Clone Drive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) (freeware) -- you won't have to deal with any adware/toolbars or lite/standard/advanced versions, and it works great on Windows 7, without any compatibility warnings.

Comment: +1 This is what I've done when it comes to Windows 7 - I gotta admin VCD is nicer, but I wouldn't have tried it except for DT not working on x64 Win7 when I needed it ^^

Comment: @arathorn - works a treat, nice not having to reboot to install the DT SPDT driver thing.

Answer (score 2):

I have runed DT on Win7 Beta, RC and now I run them on RTM. I happend to be able to test it on both 32 and 64bits versions - no issues on any of the installations. Just remember to uncheck all the garbage during installation :)

Answer (score 1):

I have only noticed one issue and that is a dialog from Microsoft telling me that Daemon Tools is not compatible and might cause issues. Ignoring this dialog has let me use it yo mount all sorts of images.

Maybe there's some of the copy protection features that's not working.

After a suggestion on this site i switched over to virtual clone drive that's supposedly crapware free :)

Answer (score 1):

I stopped using Deamon Tools Lite and went with [MagicDisc](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm) when DTL wasn't supported on the Beta and RC. Have used it ever since and find it lightweight and easy to use.

Comment: +1 - I went with the SlySoft Virtual Clone Drive but will give MagicDisc a spin on my other machine. Daemon Tools days are numbered for me now.

Answer (score 1):

Gizmo is also a great Win7-ready replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution to the problem of installing deamon tools with Windows 7 step by step
http://resolveyourproblem.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-install-deamon-tools-on-windows.html